Android - Data fetched from Firebase is not added to the list
I have a fragment in Kotlin and I am trying to get data from Firebase. I already get data from Firebase but the code does not works when it comes to add datas to "myPetsList" list. Here is my your textFragment and Adapter code:
fragment 
package com.example.touchpet

import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil
import com.example.touchpet.databinding.FragmentMyPetsBinding
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.database.*
import com.example.touchpet.MyPetsAdapter

private const val ARG_PARAM1 = "param1"

class MyPetsFragment : Fragment() {
    private var param1: String? = null
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentMyPetsBinding
    private lateinit var myPetsList: ArrayList<Pet>
    private lateinit var adapter: MyPetsAdapter
    private lateinit var firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth
    private lateinit var db: FirebaseDatabase
    private lateinit var petRef: DatabaseReference
    private lateinit var cUser: User

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater,R.layout.fragment_my_pets,container,false)
    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
    petRef = db.getReference("pet")
    myPetsList= arrayListOf()
    adapter= MyPetsAdapter(requireContext(),myPetsList)
    binding.myPetsAdapter=adapter
    getPetsData()


    Log.d("DEBUG", "List size: ${myPetsList.size}")
    return binding.root
}

fun getPetsData() {
    val userId = firebaseAuth.currentUser?.uid
    if (userId == null) {
        Log.e("FirebaseAuth", "User is not logged in")
        return
    }

    petRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            myPetsList.clear()
            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                for (petSnapshot in snapshot.children) {
                    val pet = petSnapshot.getValue(Pet::class.java)
                    Log.e("FirebasePet", "${pet?.pet_name.toString()}")
                    pet?.let { myPetsList.add(it) }
                }
                binding.myPetsAdapter?.updateItems(myPetsList)  // Notify the adapter

            } else {
                Log.d("FirebaseData", "No pets found")
            }
        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            Log.e("FirebaseError", "Database error: ${error.message}", error.toException())
            }
        })
}

companion object {
    @JvmStatic
    fun newInstance(param1:String) =
        MyPetsFragment().apply {
            arguments = Bundle().apply {
                putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1)
            }
        }
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    arguments?.let {
        param1 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM1)
    }
}

} 
package com.example.touchpet

import android.content.Context
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.touchpet.databinding.CardviewPetBinding

class MyPetsAdapter(private val mContext:Context, private var cardList: List<Pet?>)
    :RecyclerView.Adapter<MyPetsAdapter.CardTasarimNesneleriTutucu>(){
        private var listenerItems: onItemClickListener? = null
    inner class CardTasarimNesneleriTutucu(cardTasarimBinding: CardviewPetBinding, private val listener: onItemClickListener?): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(cardTasarimBinding.root),
        View.OnClickListener{
        var cardTasarimBinding: CardviewPetBinding

    init {
        this.cardTasarimBinding = cardTasarimBinding
    }

    override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        val position = adapterPosition
        if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
            listener?.onItemClick(position)
        }
    }

}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CardTasarimNesneleriTutucu {
    val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext)
    val cardTasarimBinding = CardviewPetBinding.inflate(layoutInflater,parent,false)
    return CardTasarimNesneleriTutucu(cardTasarimBinding,listenerItems)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return cardList.size
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyPetsAdapter.CardTasarimNesneleriTutucu, position: Int) {
    val card = cardList.get(position)
    holder.cardTasarimBinding.myPetNesne = card

}

fun updateItems(newItems: List<Pet>) {
    this.cardList = newItems
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}

interface onItemClickListener {
    fun onItemClick(position: Int)
}

fun setOnItemClickListener(listener: onItemClickListener) {
    listenerItems = listener
}

`}``
I debugged lots of time and I could not catch any mistakes. The only problem was adding elements to "myPetsList"

I'm not sure I understand.
What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

I can not add any element to myPetsList that I fetched from firebase.

You need to better explain what "does not works" mean. What is the expectation you have? What is the actual behavior? "I debugged lots of time" - what have you actually done to debug this?

Need more info. Does Log.e("FirebasePet", "${pet?.pet_name.toString()}") print out something?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
